Why is this trivial numba function with a List input so slow
import numba
from typing import List

@numba.njit
def test(a: List[int]) -> int:
    return 1

test([i for i in range(2_000_000)])

takes 2s and scales linearly with the size of the list.
Wrapping the input argument with numba.typed.List takes even longer. (all the time is spent on the numba.typed.List call.
The timings don't get better if the function is called multiple times (while only being defined once), i.e., this is not a matter of compilation time.
Is there a way to tell numba to just use the list as is?
In my actual application, the raw data comes from an external library that cannot return numpy arrays or numba lists directly, only Python lists.
I'm using numba 0.59.1 and Python 3.12 on a 4 core Ubuntu22 laptop with 16GB RAM.

You are generating the list in the function call before even sending it to the numba decorated function. i.e. [i for i in range(2_000_000)] must be fully evaluated before it even gets sent to the function. Of course that will run in python time and cannot be compiled away

@roganjosh creating that list in Python is almost instant

Numba only operates on typed variables. It needs not only to check the types of all the items but also convert the whole list into a typed list. This implicit conversion can be particularly expensive since CPython lists, a.k.a. reflected lists contain pointers on allocated objects and each objects is reference counted. Typed lists of Numba are homogeneous and they do not contain references but directly the value in it. This is far more efficient and similar to a Numpy array with additional features like resizing.

Is there a way to tell numba to just use the list as is?

AFAIK, no. Reflected lists are not supported any-more in Numba code. Operating on reflected lists is not only inefficient, but also break the type system.
The best option is to create directly a typed list. Here is an example:
import numba as nb

# Quite fast part (less than 0.1 seconds)
reflected_lst = [i for i in range(2_000_000)]

# Slow part (3 seconds)
typed_lst = nb.typed.typedlist.List(reflected_lst)

# Very fast part (less than 2 µs) since `lst` is already a typed-list
test(typed_lst)

As mentioned by @roganjosh, note the list generation is included in your benchmark, but this only takes a tiny fraction of the execution time (<5% on my machine).
Note the conversion process is particularly expensive in Numba (as opposed to Numpy, see the below comments). There is an opened issue on this topic. To quote the developers:

[...] we came to the conclusion that there is probably room for improvement.
[...] this problem is all down to implementation details.

As of now, the issue is still opened and there is a patch to improve a bit the performance of the conversion, but it is still rather slow with it.

This is a surprising result indeed. To convert a list to a homogenous numpy array wouldn't take anything close to that kind of time (just checked). What would it be checking for that wouldn't already throw in the numpy mechanism?

Now that I say that, I suppose the answer would be that numpy is pre-compiled while this is a type hint for the compiler from scratch

Indeed, Numpy is pretty fast for this operation and it also needs to check the types like Numba does. AFAIK, the current Numba list creation is pretty inefficient compared to Numpy and it could be significantly optimized. Note that specifying the type to Numba have no significant impact on the execution time of the list conversion (<1%). Also note that the JIT compilation/checking time takes a negligible time, except maybe the first time the provided code is run (I ran it multiple time so not to include it).

I just checked, and in practice, the first run does not take a so huge time (<20%).

@roganjosh I added information about an opened Numba issue on this specific topic ;)

Nice, thanks! It looks like it's a bit of a hot potato towards the end and might not get addressed. Still, really interesting to know this potential issue with jagged "arrays"; I was completely unaware

I still don't understand: Surely numba converting the Python list to a numba list shouldn't take orders of magnitude longer than Python creating a list (which in Python means objects all over the heap) from scratch (or from another list via list comprehension for that matter)

@Bananach well, it's trivial for a list comprehension to give mixed types: a = [1 if x // 2 == 0 else "hi" for x in range(10)] so python doesn't need to care about it being homogeneous. Numba does and surely the comments from that linked issue explain it - the implementation is poor. What more is there to say?

The timing is so bad that I'm thinking it'd be a great way to get an open source contribution under one's belt but there will be some deeper reason. Nobody could just leave a wart that big hanging around
